# Android/Camera: What parameter/conditions affect FLASH_MODE_AUTO to flash?

Tags: android

I'm setting flash mode to `AUTO` in my app, but flash does not kick off under the same conditions as under the official Android Camera app. In my app it kick off only under substantially less light.

What other parameter could have an affect on when flash should kick off?

Also, as a follow up question: is there a way to read the lighting conditions (let's say, when the camera focuses), so that I can determine `FLASH_MODE_ON` or `FLASH_MODE_OFF` programmatically myself?

I'm testing on Galaxy S III / latest CM10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you checked the scene mode that is currently set. I think camera flash works differently in different scene modes. Use `getSceneMode()` to find your current sceneMode and change it using `setSceneMode()`.

Source: [Android Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html#SCENE_MODE_ACTION)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've set scene mode to auto and did the same for white balance. It looks like I've got the same behavior now.